# Publishing to Azure with a gulp error

Tags: visual-studio, azure, gulp

I use gulp to do some publishing tasks, which due to a current inter-dependency bug means I get this error when publishing:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5): Error : (node:18928) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.`

When I publish my app to the file system (in Release mode), it completes and all is OK, even though this error is still output.

When I publish my app to Azure (also in Release mode), the build fails because of this error. I know it's because of the gulp error; I've removed the bit that causes the error and it publishes to Azure fine.

So why does it cause build failure when publishing to Azure, but it is fine when publishing to the file system? Is there any way I can get it to still publish to Azure (and save me the round-trip of FTPing the thing myself)?

Comment: Looks like some kind of continue on error flag would help

Comment: Yes, I did search for a setting of some such but I couldn't find one :(

Comment: will it be possible you to attach a minimum project with the error, removing all of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that although the publish ends with an error, it has in fact succeeded. Wasted a lot of time thinking it hand't..!